# Is there a better way to make my 2-lined column title DataFrame to a 1-lined one?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a df which looks like this:

```
>>> df
                Entite  CDTYPOPE    MTSOLDDARCV                         Total
CDTYPCONSO                                   HG              IG           
0              Entite1   BOND_TR            NaN   -101508273.92 -1.015083e+08
1              Entite1  STOCK_TR    -33000346.6   -745785338.89 -7.787857e+08
2              Entite1     Total    -33000346.6   -847293612.81 -8.802940e+08
3              Entite2   BOND_TR            NaN   -208796113.97 -2.087961e+08
4              Entite2  STOCK_TR  -103843883.37  -1277876111.78 -1.381720e+09
5              Entite2     Total  -103843883.37  -1486672225.75 -1.590516e+09
```

And I want it to look like this (I want the details of CDTYPCONSO which is **HG** and **IG** replacing MTSOLDDARCV):

```
   Entite  CDTYPOPE             HG              IG         Total
0 Entite1   BOND_TR            NaN   -101508273.92 -1.015083e+08
1 Entite1  STOCK_TR    -33000346.6   -745785338.89 -7.787857e+08
2 Entite1     Total    -33000346.6   -847293612.81 -8.802940e+08
3 Entite2   BOND_TR            NaN   -208796113.97 -2.087961e+08
4 Entite2  STOCK_TR  -103843883.37  -1277876111.78 -1.381720e+09
5 Entite2     Total  -103843883.37  -1486672225.75 -1.590516e+09
```

The following code works fine but something is telling me there is a better way to do so.

```
c=[]
for a, b in df.columns.to_list():
    c.append(b if b else a)
    
df.columns = c
```

So, is there a better way doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df['HD'] = df.xs(('MTSOLDDARCV', 'HG'))
df['IG'] = df.xs(('MTSOLDDARCV', 'IG'))
df.drop(columns='MTSOLDDARCV')
```

Comment: But what if I have a variable number of occurrences in 'MTSOLDDARCV'?
I was thinking of a solution that would involve some index manipulation